# Code does not complete or fail, just keeps on running when used @DataProvider to run a piece of code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider, xssfsheet

I am working on a Selenium-Java(Maven) project using TestNG.

I am using an excel spreadsheet to feed data for my TestNG framework to run a test case. The code works just fine if I hard code the input String values and run. But the moment I used @DataProvider, the code just runs endlessly and does not fail either until I manually stop the execution.

P.S I have used Data Provider for a sample test run by reading just one row from my excel sheet. But the moment I wrote logic to dynamically read all the rows that are data filled, the problem occurred. Need help here.

I tried rebuilding the project, But its not helping.

Following is the Code I used to read Excel data:

```
public class ExcelDataProvider {
    @DataProvider(name = "excelData")
    public Object[][] getData() throws IOException {
        String[][] data;
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\TestDataProvider\\TestDataProvider.xlsx";
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheet("Values");
        int length=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        data=new String[length][2];
        String s = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (!Objects.equals(s, "0")) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            XSSFCell cell1 = row.getCell(0);
            cell1.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
            s = cell1.getStringCellValue();
            if (Objects.equals(s, "0")) {
                break;
            }
            XSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(1);
            String val1 = cell1.getStringCellValue();
            String val2 = cell2.getStringCellValue();
            data[i][0] = val1;
            data[i][1] = val2;
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s = cell1.getStringCellValue();
 if (Objects.equals(s, "0")) {
       break;
     }
```

Since you are checking s= "0" then While dynamically reading all the rows, please Make sure the last column value as 0 then only the program will terminate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvYQD.png)

else try with getLastCellNum() method to get better control.
.
**for example:**

```
int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int lastCell = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

for(int i =1; i<=lastRow ; i++) {
    map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int j=0;j<lastCell;j++) {       

String key = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);                 
    if(Objects.nonNull(cell)) {
        String value =cell.getStringCellValue();
        map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and for the suggestion. I made sure that the last Cell value had "0". The code is working fine when checked isolated, but the moment I tried to use this as Data provider the application does not run.

Comment: And about 'getLastCellNum()' method, this returning blank row count as well. Ex: If I have just 3 rows of data filled, the method is returning over 150 row as count.

Comment: updated the above code to handle null value, try to use above it will give you 3 out of that 150